# Send Email always get error response but the email is send Angular & Node

Tags: angular, typescript, email, http-error

I send e-mails via my angular application.

```
this.emailService.sendEmail(this.name, this.email, this.message)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
      }, error => {
        console.warn(error.responseText)
        console.log({ error })
      })
```

The e-mail is sent, but it always goes to the error.
When the email is sent I get:

```
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/send-email"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
url
: 
"http://localhost:3000/send-email"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

And when I the email is not been send:

```
"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/send-email: 500 Internal Server Error"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
500
statusText
: 
"Internal Server Error"
url
: 
"http://localhost:3000/send-email"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Any idea why I always get the error?
Any ideas on how to get the status message to handle it?
Thank you!